# When should "such forth" be used?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I was just having a conversation with a friend and I said "see how far from the access point each device is, so that I can do some relocation and such forth".

She said that using *such forth* at that part of the sentence is incorrect. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idiomatic phrase is "*[and so forth](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/and_so_forth)*" which is often also used as a part of the phrase "*[and so on and so forth](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so?q=and%20so%20forth#so__27)*". It is, IMO, an elided form of "*(and so it goes on) and so it goes [forth](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forth)*".

While "*and such forth*" appears to be reasonably commonly used (going by Google's results), [this ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and%20such%20forth,and%20so%20forth,%20and%20so%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) suggests that it is at best a colloquialism or a dialectal peculiarity and at worst, a common error.

To answer the question in the title, I'd say that *and such forth* should never be used. The phrase *and so forth* should be preferred instead.

Comment: I think the OP is not concerned about the correctness of the phrase itself per se, but if its usage in her statement was incorrect.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher If the phrase itself is incorrect, so is the usage in the provided statement. I'm not sure where you see an ambiguity.

Comment: I think it's just a (mistaken) conflation of *and so forth* and *and [other] such [things]*. But it's not at all common. Google Books reports only 227 instances, compared to 161,000,000 for ["and so forth"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22and+so+forth%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and 187,000 for ["and other such things"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22and+other+such+things%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (and that's only one of the "normal" variants involving the word "such").

Comment: ...another "unremarkable" variant is ["and such like"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22and+such+like%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), with 15,000,000 results. I agree OP's phrase is effectively "non-standard" - so it's not unreasonable to call it "incorrect", even if it's no more or less "grammatical" than variants which *are* used.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Google _Search_ returned around 800k hits for "and such forth" which seemed like a substantial number to me. "And such like" is truly shudder-worthy.

Comment: @coleopterist: *and such like* was far more "standard" [a century or two ago](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+such+like%2Cand+such+forth&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=), but as you can see from that NGram, *and such forth* never had any currency.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. That's very interesting.

Answer (score 7):

It would be understandable if you said  “I can do some relocation and such” (with *[such](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/such#Pronoun)* acting as a pronoun, standing for “things like the one or ones already mentioned”), or if you said “I can do some relocation and so forth” ([1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/and_so_forth#Phrase), [2](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/and+so+forth)), but bundling the two forms together gives an untoward result.

Answer (score 3):

*So* and *such* are merely variants of the same morpheme (like *a* and *an*, or *he* and *him*)

*Such* appears modifying (and quantifying) Noun Phrases, while *so* appears elsewhere. There are a number of idioms and fixed phrases that use them.

- *It was **so** wonderful/**such** a good party that I died and went to heaven.*
- ***So** much/**Such** a large quantity of wheat was produced that they had to export some.*
- *He doesn't feel **so** depressed/**such** despair about it anymore.*

In the context here, *so forth* is the idiom because *forth* is an adverb. Alternate idioms with *such* include *such things* and *such stuff*; I would normally consider *such forth* to be a nonce blend of those idioms.

Answer (score 2):

Like many other questions here on EL&U, while answering this question too I find myself standing on the crossroads of **context**.

As far as I can understand from the dialogue between you and your friend, if you were trying to convey that *the distance of the devices from the access point allows you to do relocation and **similar** activities*, then

> so that I can do some relocation and such.

would had sufficed.

But if you meant to say that *the distance allows you to do relocation, as well as some **other** activities*, then the statement as it is does not convey it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you used it as some sort of portmanteau of *such* and *so forth*, but I'm only guessing.

That having to guess is enough to cast doubt on its correctness, or at least its usefulness.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is also used to avoid repetition in contexts when it is clear the sort of similar things you are referring to but unable to mention them . For example, processed foods are unhealthy because they contain colourings, additives and so on and so forth

Comment: Your example uses "so forth" but the question is about "such forth"... do you consider them interchangeable?